# Google Drawings: Dynamic images

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to add dynamic (changing) images to [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings)?

We have images that are generated by our server and might change over time. Instead of having to update them over and over again, it would be great to have Google Drawings re-download the embedded image automatically (or by adding any script or so).

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `add dynamic (changing) images to Google Drawings`. I apologize for this. In your goal, you want to convert an image data to the drawing of Google Document? Or, you want to update an image in Google Document? 2. Can I ask you about the mimeType of `images that are generated by our server`? 3. In your Google Document, how is the image inserted? For example, it's the inline image or the positioned image? And where is the image? For example, it's in a table cell?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike. Google Drawings is a sheet type where you can basically "draw" diagrams, add text and other objects. You can also add images by URL. We want to add an image to a drawing that might change. Like embedding an `<img>` tag on a website. I've added a link to Google Drawings in case we aren't talking about the same thing.

Comment: What is the workflow you are doing, where do those images come and go? Could you describe it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. You have a Drawing file (The mimeType is `application/vnd.google-apps.drawing`.). The Drawing has an image. You want to change the image in the Drawing using a script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in the current stage, Drawing data cannot be modified using Google APIs. For example, when Drawing data is converted to SVG data, I think that your goal can be achieved. How about this? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Kessy and Tanaike. My use case is this: we have a webcam that takes pictures on a daily base. We found Google Drawing to be the most comfortable and flexible way for adding layers (like text, shapes, other images etc) on it. So people can create their derivations and use the exported image URLs from Google Drawing anywhere. Now, the question is how we might add the webcam image to a drawing and allow it to be updated easily.

Comment: Do you mean editing the drawing from a script?